# Ubuntu 22.04: how to understand where the OS installed?

Tags: 22.04, disk

I have a 22.04 with 3 HDDs. How to detect on what disk the OS installed?
I'd like to format another disk and use it as a file storage but it contains system folders too, it seems from an old installation.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043263/which-hard-drive-have-the-os  has all you need